# Strange behaviour of `COUNT(DISTINCT field)` in SQLite

Tags: sqlite, count, distinct

I have a private database (I can not publish it in order to help getting an answer but I will describe the issue as well as possible) with at least two columns: `Numero` and `statut`:

- Each value in `Numero` can occur exactly one or two times; no row has a `NULL` value for this field;
- the value in `statut` is either a string or `NULL`.

The request

```
select count(distinct numero) from candidats where statut is not null;
```

is intended to return the number of unique `Numero` having at least one non-null `statut`; in my case I get the answer 472.

Knowing that the expected result should be 463, I also dumped the output of

```
select distinct numero from candidats where statut is not null;
```

and counted the resulting rows, finding this time the expected 463.

I can't figure out any combination of values explaining how both requets may differ.

What request would result in the 9 unexpected `Numero` values in order to let me study them and understand what is going wrong?

Comment: @J.R. I don't believe that it would. Only *`*count()`** or **`count(*)`** would, if you specify a column (as used in the question) then if that column is null it is not counted as per *The `count(X)` function returns a count of the number of times that X is not NULL in a group. The `count(*)` function (with no arguments) returns the total number of rows in the group.* [count(X) count(*)](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html#count).

Comment: The only discrepancy bewteen the two, I could see was the other way around. That is if two rows had the same value for numero but different non-null values for status then *`select count(distinct numero) from candidats where statut is not null;`* would return a lower count as the two rows would be disticnt according to numero column but not according to the distinct rows.

Comment: @MikeT Was in a rush before and revisiting it now; I think my previous statement was correct that you would have different counts if `numero` was `null` somewhere. It would not appear in the `count` of the first query but would pop up in the second query resulting in the 463 rows. It does not explain why the second query returns a lower number of rows though.